# constructing a measurable space on the natural numbers

Tags: measure-theory

1) I want to construct a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{N} $, let $\mathbb{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by {n$\mathbb{N}$| n$\in\mathbb{N} $}. what kind of finite sets would we find in $\mathbb{A}$?

2) I want to try and impose function of the form  $\lambda$:$\mathbb{A} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}^+$ where $\lambda (n \mathbb{N})=\frac{1}{n}$. can you prove that $\lambda$ can(not) be a measure on $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: so I know for example that {1} is a possible construction, by having having the naturals and then subtracting all sets of mutliples of primes. It might be problematic if someone proved that every singleton is constructible, because then I would suspect singletons would have an equal 'measure', which would mean the function in the second part can not be a measure.

Comment: ^You can extend the construction of $\{1\}$ to show that $\{n\} \in \mathbb{A}$ for every natural $n$. Fix $n$ and for a prime $p,$ let $a_n(p)$ be the largest $a$ s.t. $p^a|n.$ Subtract from $n \mathbb{N}$ all sets of the form $p^{a_n(p) + 1} \mathbb{N}$ for prime $p$. You will be left with just $\{n\}$.

Comment: Also, while I haven't proved this, since now $\mathbb{A} = 2^{\mathbb{N}},$ and it seems that $\lambda$ is the same as the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density), it shouldn't be a measure on $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: yup, that will totally do it. thanks